# How to close Ajax page display in fancybox manually?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

**I am displaying an ajax feedback form in fancy box and i need to close the fancy box once feedback send(with time delay of 20sec).**

My fancy box call is...

```
        $("#feedback").fancybox({
            'speedIn'   :   600,
            'speedOut'  :   200,
            'centerOnScroll':   false,
            'autoDimensions':   true,
                'type'          : 'ajax'

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Modify as needed.

```
$.post('/YourAjaxRequest', { your ajax data }, function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}, 'json');
```

This will close the dialog box when the request is finished, no matter how long it takes, and does not rely on a 20 second timeout. If you want to close the box 20 seconds *after* the response, you could do this:

```
$.post('/YourAjaxRequest', { your ajax data }, function() {
    setTimeout($.fancybox.close, 20000);
}, 'json');
```

To indicate that you're submitting a request, you may want to use `showActivity`:

```
$.fancybox.showActivity();
$.post('/YourAjaxRequest', { your ajax data }, function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}, 'json');
```

Comment: once i get ajax data i need to close with time span of 20 seconds. how to delay closing for some seconds

Comment: David. Help me how can i syncronise your code in fancybox ajax call. refer my above code....

Comment: @Mohan: use my code on the 'send' button, where you submit the form. this is assuming that you want to close it after the user has sent the form. if you want to close it 20 seconds after the box has been opened *regardless* of whether or not the form has been posted, or a post is in progress, you run the timeout code from my second example immediately after your first call to `$('#feedback').fancybox()`.

Comment: I am calling fancybox from parent using this $('#feedback').fancybox(). how to close from parent itself.once my ajax form in fancybox submitted entire fancy box disappears for me. kindly explain me how can i do this sir,

Comment: *wherever* (well...) and *whenever* you call `$.fancybox.close();` it will close the fancybox. If you want to call it 20 seconds after something else, you write `setTimeout($.fancybox.close, 20000)` after that something else. If you want to call it when the AJAX form is submitted, you call it in the AJAX callback, as in my first example, above.

Comment: See my codes within fancybox $("#feedback").fancybox({.....});.Within this code can i implement urs code to close it. How can i give it

Comment: Once i click form submit in ajax page. it closes i need to stop that closing and want to close manually by delaying after form submitted.

Comment: "Once i click form submit in ajax page. it closes" <- In that case it is *that* code that you need to change. The code that runs when you click form submit closes the box, and presumably submits the form. You need to *remove* the code that closes the box from the submit button, and *add* it to the AJAX callback. Please post the code for the form submit button if you want help in implementing that.

Comment: REFER THIS LINK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388354/stop-the-closing-of-an-ajax-page-displayed-in-fancybox

Comment: The code for the submit button is not included that question either (but you should add it there as well, for anyone to be able to help you answer that question)