# Stop the closing of an AJAX page displayed in fancybox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

How can I stop the closing of an AJAX page displayed in a fancybox?

```
<a href="sample.php?name=name1&feedback=feedback1" id="feedback">feedback</a>
```

fancybox code in jquery...

```
    $("#feedback").fancybox({

        'speedIn'   :   600,
        'speedOut'  :   200,
        'centerOnScroll':   false,
        'autoDimensions':   true
        'type'          : 'ajax',
        });
```

sample.php page will be displayed in fancybox. once user click submit button in sample.php. fancybox closes. i need to make delay in closing after submitting feedback form(sample.php)

Comment: My code is above. Help me to recover...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't posted code So I can only guess:

You can add this options:

```
showCloseButton: false // this will hide the close button
hideOnContentClick: false // this will not close fancybox when clicked inside
hideOnOverlayClick: false // this will not closefancyvox when clicked outside
```

You can also manually close fancybox by calling `$.fancybox.close`

You can check for more in the [API docs](http://fancybox.net/api)

Hope its what you need.

**UPDATE:**

To be able to close manually fancybox after form submit you need to post the form by ajax and close fancybox on success or failure using '`$.fancybox.close`'

You can bind the ajax to your form like this:

```
$('#yourForm').bind('submit', function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: 'yourpage.php',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'Error') { alert('An error occurred')}
    else { $.fancybox.close }
  }
});
```

});

Check the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to read more about the ajax() function and do some search in the official [fancybox support group](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox?pli=1) for more information.

Comment: sample.php is a seperate page. which is called via ajax. i need to close that page manually.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please note that this is a very general code just to give you an example. You will need to modify your code to your specific needs.