# How to call page via ajax using fancybox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I need to display a page via fancybox and once form submitted I need to close fancy box from parent window.

Comment: This is the third time you're posting essentially the same question. Please stick to one. You'll get very similar answers in this question compared to your other two, plus some fluff about how to open the box, which you already know. You really do need to include more code in your questions, to help us solve your specific problem. [Stop the closing of an AJAX page displayed in fancybox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388354/stop-the-closing-of-an-ajax-page-displayed-in-fancybox)  [How to close Ajax page display in fancybox manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4387914/133802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an already made example of the implementation you need:

http://fancybox.net/blog#login_form